# Does $E(X_{(2)}X_{(1)}^2|X_{(1)})=E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})E(X_{(1)}^2)$ hold?

Tags: probability

In the above, $X_{(1)}=\min(X_1, \ldots,X_n)$, and $X_{(2)}$ is the second order statistic of a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

I’ve encountered this identity while reading a solution to an exercise on order statistics. The questions asks to compute the LHS. Does this identity hold? If so, why? Additionally, if it is indeed correct, does it hold more generally for random variables or solely for order statistics? I’ve tried searching for an answer on MSE but couldn’t find anything resembling the above expression.

Comment: Please include the question in the body of the question, and also provide some context as to what we are looking at, e.g. what is $X_{(1)}$

Comment: $E(X_{(2)}X_{(1)}^2|X_{(1)})=E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)}) X_{(1)}^2$ by using that $X_{(1)}^2$ is a measurable function of $X_{(1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: $E(X_{(2)}X_{(1)}^2|X_{(1)}) \ne E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})E(X_{(1)}^2)$ in general case.

Proof: Suppose that $E(X_{(2)}X_{(1)}^2|X_{(1)}) = E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})E(X_{(1)}^2)$. As Lundborg already shown, $E(X_{(2)}X_{(1)}^2|X_{(1)}) = X_{(1)}^2 E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})$. Hence $E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})E(X_{(1)}^2) = X_{(1)}^2 E(X_{(2)}|X_{(1)})$. Thus  $E(X_{(1)}^2) = X_{(1)}^2$. But $E(X_{(1)}^2)$ is a constant and $X_{(1)}^2$ is not a constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you expand on why we can take $X_{(1)}^2$ out of the expectation? As I write in my comment above, it intuitively makes sense to me that if we know $X_{(1)}$ then we also know $X_{(1)}^2$ but why does this imply that we can take the squared term out of the expectation?

Comment: I reckon I don’t quite grasp the justification given by Lundborg

Comment: @Leon There's a property of conditional expectations: $⁡E(f(Z)Y\mid Z)=f(Z)) {E}(Y\mid Z).$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation. We used this property.